# Can I tell asp.net mvc to get content in xyz/?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a `file.css` thats in my root folder. Is there a way I can put it in a folder called `/content` or `/root/` so it doesn't clutter up my main project root folder?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. 
To refer to it in your view files you can do: (MVC4 / Razor v2)

```
 <link href="~/content/file.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For MVC3

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/content/file.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: @Omar fixed! added the previous MVC3 version :)

Comment: hmm. Well thats `/content/file.css`. I meant I wanted all files to assume to be in `/content`. I think i'll just attempt setting up a nginx instance and forward connections to msvs